# How do I pass an array of custom objects in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I am trying to make a main menu for an Mac application as a beginning task to learn about Swift. Here is my code, which does not work.

In the AppDelegate

```
 import Foundation
 import Cocoa

 @NSApplicationMain

 class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate
 {

     @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!

     //private let  mainWindow  =   NSWindow(frame: NSWindow.mainScreen().bounds)
     //let mainWindow =   NSWindow()
     //let statusItem = NSStatusBar.systemStatusBar().statusItemWithLength(NSSquareStatusItemLength)

     func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification)
     {
         // Insert code here to initialize your application
         let menuData = [getMainMenuItems]

         //[makeMainMenu, menuData]

     }

}
```

And then in a different project file, named Swift_FileManager

```
 import Foundation
 import Cocoa

 class menuArrayObject
 {
     var title: String = ""
     var subMenuTitles: [String] = []
 }

 func getMainMenuItems (menuData:Array<AnyObject>) -> AnyObject
 {
     //Make a new menu array
     var menuData = [AnyObject]()

     let arrayObject1 = menuArrayObject()
      arrayObject1.title = "Project"
     arrayObject1.subMenuTitles = ["New Project","Open Project","Save Project", "Quit Project"]
     menuData.append(arrayObject1)

     return menuData
 }
```

The code compiles but the function `getMainMenuItems` is never called.

Can somebody shed some light on the (probably very simple) issue here? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let menuData = [getMainMenuItems]
```

This line (probably) isn't doing what you think it's doing. What it's doing is creating an array of `[(Array<AnyObject>)->(AnyObject)]` type (an array of functions that take an array of `AnyObjects` as input, and return an `AnyObject`) – and adding your `getMainMenuItems` function to it.

It's not calling your function at all.

In order to call a function, you need to use a pair of brackets `()`, containing the required input. In this case, your `getMainMenuItems` method expects an array of `AnyObjects` (although it never appears to actually use them).

For example:

```
let menuData = getMainMenuItems([/* Insert your objects here */])
```

---

Although that all being said, I'm not entirely sure that your `getMainMenuItems` function actually needs an input, as you never use it. I think you're looking for something like this:

```
func getMainMenuItems() -> [MenuArrayObject] {

    // create an empty array of MenuArrayObjects
    var menuData = [MenuArrayObject]()

    let arrayObject1 = MenuArrayObject()
    arrayObject1.title = "Project"
    arrayObject1.subMenuTitles = ["New Project","Open Project","Save Project", "Quit Project"]
    menuData.append(arrayObject1)

    return menuData
}
```

Note that the function no longer has an input, and I've replaced `AnyObject` with `[MenuArrayObject]`. It's best to be as type specific as you can in Swift (and pretty much every other OOP language), so you should really steer away from `AnyObject` unless you have good reason to use it.

Now you can just invoke your function like this:

```
let menuData = getMainMenuItems()
```

and it will return an array of `MenuArrayObjects`.

If you're trying to make the function so that it'll add an object to an already existing array, then you can use an [`inout` parameter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH34-ID545) in your function. This will let you pass an array into your function, which it can modify.

For example:

```
func getMainMenuItems(inout menuData:[MenuArrayObject]) {

    let arrayObject1 = MenuArrayObject()
    arrayObject1.title = "Project"
    arrayObject1.subMenuTitles = ["New Project","Open Project","Save Project", "Quit Project"]
    menuData.append(arrayObject1)
}
```

You can then call it like so:

```
// an existing array of MenuArrayObjects
var menuDataArray = [MenuArrayObject]()

// call function with array – which it will append an element to
getMainMenuItems(&menuDataArray)
```

Comment: @user1976727 Happy to help :) I have added some extra information about how you should probably be using your `getMainMenuItems` function to my answer if you're interested.

Answer (score 0):

The code `let menuData = [getMainMenuItems]` is just creating an array containing the function. I'm guessing that you mean to call the function instead. That looks something like:

```
let menuData = getMainMenuItems([])
```

Answer (score 0):

In applicationDidFinishLaunching you need to instantiate menuArrayObject:

```
let myMenuArray = menuArrayObject()
```

And then call it:

```
let menuData = myMenuArray.getMainMenuItems()
```

Your getMainMenuItems method, it seems looking at what you wrote in the method, should be defined as:

```
func getMainMenuItems() -> [AnyObject]
```